# Should do I use screen or tmux commands?

Tags: unix, tmux, gnu-screen

I would like to know the main differences between tmux and screen commands to manage my machine.

My problem is that I have to run a process that I will launch be SSH, but that have to be alive all the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for a good answer and I found this while I was googling.

Tmux is easier to do searches because you have a unique name, is a faster screen drawing and the most important thing, far less memory usage than screen.

Example:

- 100 windows in screen = 370MB resident
- 100 windows in tmux = just 5MB resident